# Mostrar información detallada en un nuevo Actitivity al seleccionar un item de un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, recyclerview

He creado un RecyclerView de Cardviews en un Fragment; al seleccionar uno de los items necesito que se muestre su detalle en el ShowDetailActivity(). La información de estos items se carga desde Realtime Database de Firebase.

Este es el código de la clase Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ShowsViewHolder> {
List<Show> shows;
Activity activity;


public Adapter(List<Show> shows) {
    this.shows= shows;
}

@Override
public ShowsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_tvshow, 
parent, false);

    final ShowsViewHolder holder= new ShowsViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
 }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShowsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Show show= shows.get(position);
    holder.textViewNombre.setText(shows.get(position).getName_show());
    holder.textViewDescripcion.setText(shows.get(position).getDesc_show());
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(show.getImg_show()).into(holder.imageViewShow);

    holder.imageViewShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Test click"+String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShowDetailActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return shows.size();
}

public static class ShowsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewNombre;
    TextView textViewDescripcion;
    ImageView imageViewShow;
    CardView item_show;

    TextView textViewNombreDetail;
    TextView textViewDescripcionDetail;
    ImageView imageViewShowDetail;


    public ShowsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewNombre= itemView.findViewById(R.id.showNameCard);
        textViewDescripcion= itemView.findViewById(R.id.showDescCard);
        imageViewShow= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgShowCard);

        textViewNombreDetail= itemView.findViewById(R.id.showNameDetail);
        textViewDescripcionDetail= itemView.findViewById(R.id.showDescDetail);
        imageViewShowDetail= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageShowDetail);
    }
  }
}
```

Clase del Fragment donde se muestra el RecyclerView:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        List<Show> shows;
        Adapter adapter;


        public HomeFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            showToolbar(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_home), false, view);

            RecyclerView showsRecycler= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.showRecycler);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

            showsRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            shows= new ArrayList<>();

            FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            adapter= new Adapter(shows);
            showsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);


            database.getReference().getRoot().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    shows.removeAll(shows);
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot:
                            dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Show show= snapshot.getValue(Show.class);
                        shows.add(show);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
                {

                }
            });


    return view;

}

public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton, View view){
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
  }
}
```

Pero no estoy segura como pasar la información detallada del item que seleccioné al activity "ShowDetailActivity" traída desde Firebase. En el método onclick del onBindViewHolder funciona el intent y todo bien, pero no muestra la información del item seleccionado.

He intentado escribiendo en el `onClick(): ?
holder.textViewNombreDetail.setText(shows.get(position).getName_show());`
pero me da este error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Pero... ¿cuál es el problema en sí?

Comment: Para pasar la info a la actividad debes crear una interface e implementarla en el oncliclistener de tu itemview, o puedes pasarle un listener al constructor en implementarlo, pero aun no entiendo muy bien tu problema, pero puedes trabajar el clicllistener en tu viewholder

Comment: En que no estoy segura como pasar la información detallada del item que seleccioné al activity "ShowDetailActivity" traída desde Firebase. En el método onclick del onBindViewHolder funciona el intent y todo bien, pero no muestra la información del item seleccionado. He intentado escribiendo en el onClick(): holder.textViewNombreDetail.setText(shows.get(position).getName_show());  pero me da este error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para abrir un Fragment y enviarle datos, aquí la respuesta:
[¿Como llamar un fragment desde un RecyclerView Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175366/como-llamar-un-fragment-desde-un-recyclerview-android)

Para abrir un Activity, recuerda tenerla ya declarada en el `manifest`.
Los datos se envian a través de `intent`, y también con intent se abre la activity.
Te falta declarar el id del `CardView` dentro de `super(itemView)`:

```
item_show = itemView.findViewById(R.id.elIDdetuCardView);
```

Dentro de tu `ViewHolder` (ShowsViewHolder) implementa un ClickListener al cardView:

```
  super(itemView);
  item_show = itemView.findViewById(R.id.elIDdetuCardView);
  textViewNombre= itemView.findViewById(R.id.showNameCard);
  .....

  item_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ShowDetailActivity.class);
                // envías los TextView de esta forma:
                intent.putExtra("clave1", textViewNombre.getText());
                // para las imágenes de esta forma:
                intent.putExtra("clave2", shows.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImg_show());
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

En tu activity recibes los `Bundle extras`:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tu_layout);
    TextView texto1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tu_id_text);
    ImageView imagen1 = ....

    //de esta forma obtienes los valores que enviastes por intent:
    String value1 = "";
    int value2 = 0;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras !=null){
        value1 = extras.getString("clave1");
        value2 = extras.getInt("clave2");
    }

     // y así los configuras
    texto1.setText(value1);
    //imagen1.setImageResource(value2);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(value2)
            .into(imagen1);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!! Me salvaste la vida!!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando vas a la otra activity en esta linea

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShowDetailActivity.class);
```

puedes llevar informacion con putExtra()

para usarlo debes hacer lo siguiente, por ejemplo para obtener la descripcion del texto en tu otra Activity `ShowDetailActivity()`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShowDetailActivity.class);
    String descripcion = shows.get(position).getDesc_show();
    intent.putExtra("String_Descripcion",descripcion);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

asi podes hacer con lo que necesites, y solamente en tu `ShowDetailActivity.class`  obtienes ese valor de esta forma , lo podes llamar en el `onCreate()`

```
String descripcion;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        descripcion= null;
    } else {
        descripcion= extras.getString("String_Descripcion");
    }
} else {
    descripcion= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("String_Descripcion");
}
```

y si quieres puedes ponerselo a algun TextView

```
mTextView.setText(descripcion);
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola! Me muestra el error "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String" en esta línea -> String descripcion = holder.textViewDescripcion.setText(shows.get(position).getDesc_show());

Comment: hola, si, me apresure cuando respondi y me olvide de sacar la primera parte, ahi edite la respuestas, de todas formas es con el putExtra donde se pasan valores