# ¿Cómo actualizar un registro de base de datos desde RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

Estoy usando arquitectura de componentes de Android, uso Room para la base datos y paginación con la librería de android.

Tengo un recyclerview que muestra registros y en cada item hay un botón de favorito, esto para guardar registros importantes que no deseen eliminar (tengo implementado onClickListener).

Las operaciones con la base de datos las realizo desde un ViewModel, pero desde el viewHolder del RecyclerAdapter no puedo acceder a él y ese es mi problema; no puedo actualizar el registro de base datos desde el onclick del viewHolder, más bién no sé cómo.
ya que debo acceder por medio de `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);` pero este usa una Activity o Fragment como parámetro y el RecyclerAdapter no lo es.

Pensé en pasar el viewModel al recyclerAdapter pero no tengo idea si es posible ya que he buscado información y no encuentro cómo.

Mi ViewModel:

```
public class TimeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    ...

    public void updateTime(Time time) { mRepository.update(time);}

}
```

mi Fragment:

```
    ...
    mTimeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TimeViewModel.class);
    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    TimeListAdapter adapter = new TimeListAdapter(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mTimeViewModel.getAllTimes().observe(this, adapter::submitList);
    ...
```

Mi RecyclerAdapter:

```
public class TimesAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Time, TimesAdapter.TimeViewHolder>{

    public class TimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private final TextView tvTime;
        private final ImageButton btFavorite;

        public TimeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
            btFavorite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btFavorite);

            btFavorite.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Time time = getItem(getAdapterPosition());

            if(v.getId() == R.id.btFavorite) {
                if(time.getFavorite() == 0) {
                    time.setFavorite(1); // 1 para favorito
                    btFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_on);

                    //Aquí quiero llamar a "updateTime(time)" del viemodel
                    //para actualizar mi registro.

                }
                else {
                    time.setFavorite(0);
                    btFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_off);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    protected TimesAdapter(Context context) {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.times_info, parent, false);
            return new TimeViewHolder(itemView);
        }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TimeViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Time current = getItem(position);
        if(current != null){
            holder.tvTime.setText(current.getTime());

            if(current.getFavorite() == 0)
                holder.btFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_off);
            else
                holder.btFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_on);
        }
        else{
            holder.tvTime.setText("Sin datos");
        }
    }

    private static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Time> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Time>() {

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(Time oldItem, Time newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(Time oldItem, Time newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }
    };

}
```

Les agradecería cualquier idea para lograr mi objetivo, solo quiero actualizar el registro en la base de datos una vez que el usuario marque o desmarque la estrella de favorito de cada item.

Comment: Hola Lalodev, por favor podrias poner tu clase Adapter completa para que te pueda decir como hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias @SantiagoCeladaGonzalez, ya he añadido la clase adapter completa.

Comment: debes de instanciar el fragment o activity(donde creas los datos) al hacer onclick en el recyclerview. Checa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175496/mostrar-informaci%C3%B3n-detallada-en-un-nuevo-actitivity-al-seleccionar-un-item-de-u/175531#175531