# RecyclerView con setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, recyclerview

Estoy utilizando Firebase como base de datos y un recyclerview para traer los datos guardados, actualmente puedo traer tanto como la imagen como el nombre de esa imagen en mi recyclerview, pero ahora quisiera poder darle click al recyclerview y se abra un nuevo fragment o activity donde pueda mostrar la misma imagen o post que se clickeo, es decir que salga la foto, el nombre y poder incluir otros datos dentro de ese nuevo fragment o activity al clickear en el post del recyclerview.

En pocas palabras por ejemplo: un tienda de ropa, tiene sus recyclerview con sus productos y tu al darle  click se abre ese producto pero  con todos los demas detalles y especificaciones que tiene.

Actualmente estoy usando:
Firebase
Navegation button con fragments

**Fragment donde se muestra el recyclerview:**

```
mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Uploads uploads = postSnapshot.getValue(Uploads.class);
            mUploads.add(uploads);
        }

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mUploads);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
return v;
```

**Adaptador del recyclerview:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
   private Context mContext;
   private List<Uploads> mUploads;

   public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Uploads> uploads) {
       mContext = context;
       mUploads = uploads;
   }

   @Override
   public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.home_item, parent, false);
       return new ImageViewHolder(v);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Uploads uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
       holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
       Picasso.get()
               .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
               .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
               .into(holder.imageView);

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return mUploads.size();
   }

   public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       public TextView textViewName;
       public ImageView imageView;

       public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Descripcion);
           imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagePro);

       }
   }
}
```

Uploads

```
public class Uploads {

    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Uploads() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Uploads(String name, String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }

        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrias poner tu clase Uploads para poder ayudarte :D

Comment: Seria bueno que lo pongas en tu pregunta, editalo porque no se ve bien alli

Comment: Listo..........

Comment: Hola, llegando a mi casa te ingreso mi soluciom. Pero en pocas palabras deberias crear un activity donde se mostrara el objeto. Luego al hacer clic al item llamar al onItemClickListener y que realize el Intent al nuevo activity donde envies el objeto Upload. Para ello importa la clase Serializable en la clase upload para poderlo enviarlo en el Bundle del Intent. Igual llegandl a mi casa te pongo toda la solucion.

Comment: ya hay respuestas para eso: si quieres mostrar detalle en una activity: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175496/mostrar-informaci%C3%B3n-detallada-en-un-nuevo-actitivity-al-seleccionar-un-item-de-u/175531#175531, y para fragment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175366/como-llamar-un-fragment-desde-un-recyclerview-android/175437#175437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, pon importa la clase `Serializable` en tu clase `Uploads`

```
public class Uploads implements Serializable {

    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Uploads() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Uploads(String name, String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }

        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Luego, crea un nuevo Activity llamado `DetailActivity.class`

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivPhoto;
    TextView tvName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Uploads uploads = (Uploads) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("uploads");
        ivPhoto=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        tvName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvName.setText(uploads.getName());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploads.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }
}
```

El `activity_detail.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Actualiza tu clase `ImageAdapter` al siguiente, 
PD: Ira a la siguiente pantalla al hacer click al textview `textViewName`

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
   private Context mContext;
   private List<Uploads> mUploads;

   public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Uploads> uploads) {
       mContext = context;
       mUploads = uploads;
   }

   @Override
   public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.home_item, parent, false);
       return new ImageViewHolder(v);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Uploads uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
       holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
       //Aca en vez de textViewName pon el contenedor 
       holder.textViewName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putSerializable("uploads",uploadCurrent);
               //Pasa el contexto en el primer parametro
               Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
               intent.putExtras(bundle);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
       Picasso.get()
               .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
               .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
               .into(holder.imageView);

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return mUploads.size();
   }

   public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       public TextView textViewName;
       public ImageView imageView;

       public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Descripcion);
           imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagePro);

       }
   }
}
```

Saludos, me avisas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, mejor explicado imposible, me ha funcionado. Finalmente ayer por la noche encontre una forma de hacerlo, pero cada vez que pasaba los datos tenia que guardar cada uno en un putextra, ahora con tu codigo no necesito hacerlo.

Comment: No, te preocupes, solo pon como solucionado :D tu post

Comment: Una pregunta extra, cuando cargo la imagen y su nombre utilizo la clase Uploads, entonces quisiera saber si ahora tuviera que cargar una imagen y en vez de "nombre" necesitara "color", entonces debo crear una nueva clase donde declare imagen y color? o puedo crear dos clases, donde en la primera extienda de la que solo contendra imagen y en la nueva nombre y en la otra extienda de la que solo tiene imagen y a esta le pongo color? Es decir que si a la hora de cargar el post, tuviera la segun la categoria seleccionada añadir los datos necesarios para cada categoria.

Comment: mmm, dependeria de como hagas tu bd de firebase, si lo solo agregas al Objeto Uploads las variables imagen y color, solo agregalos como lo tienes ahorita, pero si un tu bd de firebase crear un objeto llamado dataExtra (un ejemplo) y luego alli pones las variables imagen y color, tendrias que crear tu clase DataExtra agregar alli las variables imagen y color (no olvides de tambien implementar la clase Serializable) y luego agregar a tu clase Upload una variable llamado DataExtra (private DataExtra dataExtra;) nada mas :D. Saludos

Comment: Hola una consulta, con la clase Uploads como la tengo obtengo bien esos datos, ahora cuando le doy al boton que me abre otra activity, entonces cree otra clase Uploads2 y con sus respectivas variables y constructor. El punto es que cuando agrego esos datos al darle click en el boton de esta segunda activity, me remplaza los datos de la primera activity donde usaba Uploads, (si se que estoy dentro del mismo child porque lo que quiero es en la primera activity agregar los datos de Uploads y en la segunda activity agregar los datos de Uploads dos) la segunda complementa los datos de la primera.

Comment: Si no me explique, quise decir que: <nodo... <..child 1... en child 1 agregar los datos de Uploads y tambien los datos de Uploads2 sin sobreescribir o eliminar los de Uploads.

Answer (score 1):

No deberias pasar la imagen por extra a tu otra clase, simplemente pasa la url de la imagen y volvela a llamar con Glide desde el otro lado, como glide funciona con cache, si la foto ya la cargaste la deberia traer de cache y no volverla a cargar, para ir a otra Activity que necesites con los datos , solamente podes implementar en tu `imageViewHolder` un `onClickListener`

```
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
       public TextView textViewName;
       public ImageView imageView;

       public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
           textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Descripcion);
           imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagePro);

       }

   @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,SegundaActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("imageURL", mUploads.getImageUrl());
           mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Luego en tu otra Activity tomas la url de la imagen y la volves a cargar con

```
String imageURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageURL");
Picasso.get()
               .load(imageURL)
               .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
               .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Buena respueta, dices que Glide utuliza cache, hoy dia estoy utilizando Picasso para cargar y mostrar la imagen, pero cuando estoy en la activity donde se muestra la imagen, entonces cada vez que bajo hacia otras imagenes (ya que es un recyclerview) cuando vuelvo a subir a la primera imagen o simplemente vuelvo a subir se van volviendo a cargar las imagenes como si fueran la primera vez, es decir que Picasso no esta utilizando cache, es posible utiizar cache con piscaso o me recomiendas que cambie todo a Glide?

Comment: Perdón, me confundí, si, Glide para mí siempre fue mejor que Picasso, decime luego si te sirvió la repuesta , un saludo