# Android Studio // Obtener texto de recycler para realizar una busqueda personalizada en base de datos

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

tengo un problema con mi proyecto de android, no consigo obtener el texto de un campo en un recyclerview para realizar una busqueda mas personalizada.
Mi proyecto lo estoy realizando con un solo Activity y el resto son solamente fragments donde en estos fragments realizo consultas a una base de datos (MySQL).
Para ejemplificar el problema lo mostrare con imagenes.

[image: Imagen de fragment 1]
[image: Imagen de fragment con detalles]

En la imagen de la izquierda obtengo unos nombres desde mi base de datos. Para llenar los campos ocupo un recyclerview (con un fragment y su respectivo layout). 
La idea es que cuando haga click en algun nombre, me lleve al fragment de la derecha y este que me indique sus detalles. 
La parte de que al momento que clickee un nombre navegue hacia el otro fragment la tengo hecha, pero sin que me cargue los detalles, solo me muestra el diseño (en la imagen saque los datos directos y omitan el boton de la derecha, tengo que borrarlo, la idea es que cargue solo).

He buscado como realizar la operación pero no he podido hacerlo.
No como referenciar los nombres de la izquierda para hacer el respectivo llamado.

Mis codigos son los siguientes:

Imagen izquierda:

```
public class ver_lineas extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{

View vista;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
ProgressDialog progreso;
ArrayList<Lineas> listaLineas;
RecyclerView recyclerLineas;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ver_lineas, container, false);


    listaLineas=new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerLineas=vista.findViewById(R.id.recycler_lineas);
    recyclerLineas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
    recyclerLineas.setHasFixedSize(true);

    cargarWebService();

    return vista;
}

private void cargarWebService() {
    progreso=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progreso.setMessage("Consultando...");
    progreso.show();

    String ip= getString(R.string.ip);
    String url=ip+"/android/consulta_linea_btn.php?";

    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    VolleySingleton.getInstanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    progreso.hide();
    //Message no data in data base
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se pudo consultar "+volleyError.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se encontrarón datos de línas",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("Error",volleyError.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    progreso.hide();
    //Response message
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Mensaje: "+jsonObject,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Datos consultados exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Lineas lineas = null;

    JSONArray json = jsonObject.optJSONArray("LINEA");

    try {
        for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {
            lineas=new Lineas();
            JSONObject jsonObjecto= null;
            jsonObjecto=json.getJSONObject(i);
            lineas.setNombre_linea(jsonObjecto.optString("nombre_linea"));
            listaLineas.add(lineas);
        }
        progreso.hide();
        lineas_adapter adapter = new lineas_adapter(listaLineas);
        recyclerLineas.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ver_lineas_detalle detalle_lineas = new ver_lineas_detalle();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.layout_contenido, detalle_lineas);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Message no conection
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha establecido conexion con el servidor "+jsonObject, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha establecido conexion con el servidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Imagen derecha:

```
public class ver_lineas_detalle extends Fragment implements 
Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener {
EditText id_linea;
TextView id_ciudad, nombre_linea, descripcion_linea;
Button btnConsulta, nom_linea;
ProgressDialog progreso;

RequestQueue request;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ver_lineas_detalle, 
 container, false);
    //Reference to objects
    id_linea = vista.findViewById(R.id.text_res_linea_id);
    id_ciudad = vista.findViewById(R.id.text_res_ciudad_id);
    nombre_linea = vista.findViewById(R.id.text_res_linea_nombre);
    descripcion_linea = vista.findViewById(R.id.text_res_linea_descripcion);
    btnConsulta = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_consulta_lineas_detalle);

    request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    cargarWebService();
    return vista;
}

private void cargarWebService() {

    progreso=new ProgressDialog((getContext()));
    progreso.setMessage("Consultando...");
    progreso.show();

    String ip = getString(R.string.ip);

    //AQUI ME IMAGINO QUE DEBE IR ALGUNA VARIABLE, PERO NO SE CUAL

    String url=ip+"/android/test_lineas.php?nombre_linea=linea88";

    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, 
 this,this);
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    progreso.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se pudo consultar "+volleyError.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("Error",volleyError.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    progreso.hide();
    //Show loaded data
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Mensaje: "+jsonObject,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Datos cargados exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Lineas lineas = new Lineas();
    JSONArray json=jsonObject.optJSONArray("LINEA");
    JSONObject jsonObjecto= null;

    try {
        jsonObjecto = json.getJSONObject(0);
        //lineas.setId_linea(jsonObjecto.optString("id_linea"));
        lineas.setId_ciudad(jsonObjecto.optString("id_ciudad"));
        lineas.setNombre_linea(jsonObjecto.optString("nombre_linea"));
        lineas.setDescripcion_linea(jsonObjecto.optString("descripcion_linea"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Set text to variables
    id_linea.setText(lineas.getId_linea());
    id_ciudad.setText(lineas.getId_ciudad());
    nombre_linea.setText(lineas.getNombre_linea());
    descripcion_linea.setText(lineas.getDescripcion_linea());
}
}
```

El XML del fragment de la izquierda:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Negro"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fragments.ver_lineas">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_ver_lineas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_verinfo_lineas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ver información sobre líneas"
        android:textColor="@color/Blanco"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_lineas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adaptador:

```
public class lineas_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<lineas_adapter.LineasHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {


List<Lineas> listaLineas;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

public lineas_adapter(List<Lineas> listaLineas) {
    this.listaLineas = listaLineas;
}



@Override
public LineasHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recy_list_buttons_lineas,parent,false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    vista.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new LineasHolder(vista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LineasHolder lineasHolder, int position) {
    lineasHolder.txtLineas.setText((listaLineas.get(position).getNombre_linea()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return listaLineas.size();
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(listener!=null) {
        listener.onClick(v);
    }

}


public class LineasHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtLineas;

    public LineasHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtLineas = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_buttons_lineas);
    }
}
}
```

RecyclerView:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Negro"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_buttons_lineas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_buttons_lineas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="sample_text"
        android:textColor="@color/Blanco"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

De antemano muchas gracias, estoy atento a cualquier comentario. Saludos.

Comment: debes de instanciar el fragment detalle en el fragment ver_lineas, que por cierto las clases deben ser en mayúsculas(VerLineas). Aquí un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175366/como-llamar-un-fragment-desde-un-recyclerview-android/175437#175437

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisarlo!

Comment: Lo solucioné haciendo un interface y con la ayuda de Bundle tambien en un Patrón Maestro-detalle. Por si a alguien le sirve.