# Necesito traer una position

Tags: java, android

tengo un recycler view con varios cardview y necesito que con un boton abra un dialog desde el cual meta un texto y edite los textview que hay dentro del cardview dentro del recycler view. Ya tengo como poder editar todo pero no se como pasar la posicion de los textview

Necesito saber como puedo enviar una posicion cuando solo estoy enviando strings. en el mismo codigo digo donde necesito la posicion para poder editar los textview que hay dentro del card view con el dialog

Esta es la main activity, tambien tiene otras funciones con el boton de enviar (sendPing) pero eso esta solucionado

```
/**
 * CREATE THE CARD VIEW AND RECYCLER VIEW
 * @param position
 */

public void changeNumber (int position, String number){
    mNumberList.get(position).changePhoneNumber(number);
    mAdapterCard.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void changeEmail(int position,String email){
    mNumberList.get(position).changeEmail(email);
    mAdapterCard.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void changeSimCard(int position,String simcardnumber){
    mNumberList.get(position).changeSimCardNumber(simcardnumber);
    mAdapterCard.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void changeLastContact (int position, String text) {
    mNumberList.get(position).changeContactText(text);
    mAdapterCard.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void createNumberPhoneList(){
    mNumberList = new ArrayList<>();
    mNumberList.add(new NumberPhoneCardView("635207705","erikcr1995@gmail.com","SimCard1", "Last Contact"));
    mNumberList.add(new NumberPhoneCardView("Add Number", "add email","Simcard","Last Contact"));
}

public void buildRecyclerView(){
    mRecyclerViewCard = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerViewCard.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManagerCard = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapterCard = new NumberPhoneAdapter(mNumberList);

    mRecyclerViewCard.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerCard);
    mRecyclerViewCard.setAdapter(mAdapterCard);

    mAdapterCard.setOnItemClickListener(new NumberPhoneAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEditClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(DeviceDetailActivity.this, "editing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            openDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPingClick(int position) {
            final String phoneNum = mNumberList.get(position).getPhone();
            if (checkPermissions() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNum) && Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phoneNum).matches()) {
                resultText.setText(null);
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendDataMessage(phoneNum, null, (short) 9200, payload, sentPI, deliveryPI);

                //Get  date
                Date hourdateFormat = new Date();
                String finalDate = "Last Contact " + hourdateFormat;
                changeLastContact(position, finalDate);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(DeviceDetailActivity.this, "calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}



/**
 * OPEN THE DIALOG
 */

   @Override
     public void applyTexts(String numberDialog, String emailDialog, String simcardDialog) {
    changeNumber(position/*meter una posicion valida aqui, 
                           esta posicion debe ser el textview del cardview que tengo*/, numberDialog);
    changeEmail(position/*meter una posicion valida aqui*/, emailDialog);
}

public void openDialog(){
    editSmsDialog editSmsDialog = new editSmsDialog();
    editSmsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "edit sms dialog");
}
```

Este es el dialog

```
public class editSmsDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private EditText editNumberDialog;
    private EditText editEmailDialog;
    private EditText editSimcarDialog;

    private DialogListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sms_change, null);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Edit the parameters")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String numberDialog = editNumberDialog.getText().toString();
                        String emailDialog = editEmailDialog.getText().toString();
                        String simcardDialog = editSimcarDialog.getText().toString();
                        listener.applyTexts(numberDialog, emailDialog, simcardDialog);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //TODO WHEN CLICK CANCEL

                }
        });

        editNumberDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.editNumberDialog);
        editEmailDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.editEmailDialog);
        editSimcarDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.editSimCardDialog);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener = (DialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement DialogListener");
        }
    }

    public interface DialogListener{
        void applyTexts(String numberDialog, String emailDialog, String simcardDialog);
    }
}

Tambien paso por si acaso el adapter del recycler view

> public class NumberPhoneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NumberPhoneAdapter.NumberPhoneHolder> {

    private ArrayList<NumberPhoneCardView> numberPhoneList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onEditClick(int position);
        void onPingClick(int position);
        void onCallClick (int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }


    public static class NumberPhoneHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView numberPhone;
        public TextView email;
        public TextView simcard;
        public TextView lastContact;
        public ImageView editImage;
        public ImageView sendPingImage;
        public ImageView callNumberImage;

        public NumberPhoneHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener){
            super(itemView);
            editImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
            sendPingImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendPing);
            callNumberImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.callNumber);

            numberPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberCard);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailCard);
            simcard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.simcard);
            lastContact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastContact);

            editImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onEditClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            sendPingImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onPingClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            callNumberImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onCallClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public NumberPhoneAdapter(ArrayList<NumberPhoneCardView> numberList){
        numberPhoneList = numberList;
    }

    @Override
    public NumberPhoneHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.number_phone_card_view, parent, false);
        NumberPhoneHolder nph = new NumberPhoneHolder(v, mListener);
        return nph;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NumberPhoneHolder holder, int position) {
        NumberPhoneCardView currentItem = numberPhoneList.get(position);
        holder.numberPhone.setText(currentItem.getPhone());
        holder.email.setText(currentItem.getMail());
        holder.simcard.setText(currentItem.getSim());
        holder.lastContact.setText(currentItem.getContact());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return numberPhoneList.size();
    }
}
```

y por si acaso tambien el del card view

```
public class NumberPhoneCardView{

    private String PhoneCard;
    private String mailCard;
    private String simCard;
    private String lastContact;

    public NumberPhoneCardView (String numberPhone, String email, String simcard, String contact){
        PhoneCard = numberPhone;
        mailCard = email;
        simCard = simcard;
        lastContact = contact;
    }

    public void changePhoneNumber(String number){
        PhoneCard = number;
    }

    public void changeEmail(String email){
        mailCard = email;
    }

    public void changeSimCardNumber(String simcardnumber){
        simCard = simcardnumber;
    }

    public void changeContactText(String text){
        lastContact= text;
    }


    public String getPhone(){
        return PhoneCard;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mailCard;
    }

    public String getSim(){
        return simCard;
    }

    public String getContact(){
        return lastContact;
    }
}
```

Comment: simplemente al hacer click en un cardView se abre el DialogFragment, aquí una respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175366/como-llamar-un-fragment-desde-un-recyclerview-android

Comment: He realizado añadido el metodo local broadcast y con eso me ha funcionado todo correctamente, dejo el link de donde he recogido la informacion para poner mi localbroadcast 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager/8875292#8875292